# Accessing page methods from command in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I'm building Sitecore sheer UI application. The main layout is `aspx` page NOT XAML, which contains a grid. I added a dropdown list as a ribbon button. When dropdown list changes, it must filter the grid source based on the selected value in dropdown.

When dropdown list changes, my custom command will trigger, but in the command I can't access my grid control so that I can do a filter. So my question is how can I call a method inside my `aspx` page from command class?

Answer (score 0):

From your post I understand you have build an interface(.aspx page) which opens when user clicks dropdown value from the ribbon.

If this is the case then you can pass dropdown value in aspx page using querystring from your **command file**

1. In command file add following code

   - In **execute** method retrieve clicked value from **CommandContext context**:

     ```
     Item item = context.Items[0];
     ```
   - In **run** method user SheerResponse to open aspx file:

     ```
     UrlString urlString = new UrlString("youraspxpage.aspx?id="+(Dropdownvalue));
     SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(urlString.ToString());
     ```
2. In aspx file add following code to access which option you have selected from the 
   dropdown:

   - In page_load method access dropdown value from querystring, retrieve dropdown value and  load grid:

     ```
     string dropdownvalue= (Request.QueryString["id"]);
     ```

Let me know if the case is different. 
Thx.